# BLE Connection between iPhone and iPad with JustWorks bonding

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm currently working on a app that needs to send data from a iPhone to a iPad. I've been able to find the devices and connecting them by using both the `CentralManager` and `PeriphiralManager`. However right now it's showing me a message to asking to pair every single time. But when I press the "NO" option it will still bond by using JustWorks (at least it seems because when I go to bluetooth in settings it will just say "iPad" and I can't see information about the device other than that and it disappears from the list completely when I disconnect).

I was wondering how I could make sure the popup asking for pairing doesn't show up at all. I read somewhere to disable encryption on the Peripheral however I'm not sure how to do this when the iPad for instance is the Peripheral. The code I'm using right now looks as follows (this is the first time I'm working with `corebluetooth` and I'm currently still messing around with it and trying to get a grasp of how it works).

```
import UIKit
import CoreBluetooth
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var receiveLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var sendButton: UIButton!

    var centralManager: CBCentralManager!
    var peripheralManager: CBPeripheralManager!
    var peripherals: [CBPeripheral] = []
    var keepScanning: Bool = false

    private var timerScanInterval: TimeInterval = 5
    static let SERVICE_UUID = CBUUID(string: "4DF91029-B356-463E-9F48-BAB077BF3EF5")
    static let RX_UUID = CBUUID(string: "3B66D024-2336-4F22-A980-8095F4898C42")
    static let RX_PROPERTIES: CBCharacteristicProperties = .write
    static let RX_PERMISSIONS: CBAttributePermissions = .writeable

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: DispatchQueue.main)
        peripheralManager = CBPeripheralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
    }

}

extension ViewController {

    @IBAction func sendMessage(_ sender: UIButton) {
        for per in peripherals {
            centralManager.connect(per, options: nil)
        }

    }

    func updateAdvertisingData() {
        if peripheralManager.isAdvertising {
            peripheralManager.stopAdvertising()
        }

        peripheralManager.startAdvertising([CBAdvertisementDataServiceUUIDsKey: [ViewController.SERVICE_UUID], CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey: "Test"])
    }

    func initService() {

        let serialService = CBMutableService(type: ViewController.SERVICE_UUID, primary: true)
        let rx = CBMutableCharacteristic(type: ViewController.RX_UUID, properties: ViewController.RX_PROPERTIES, value: nil, permissions: ViewController.RX_PERMISSIONS)
        serialService.characteristics = [rx]

        peripheralManager.add(serialService)
    }

}

extension ViewController: CBCentralManagerDelegate {

    func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
        switch central.state {
        case .poweredOn:
            centralManager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: [ViewController.SERVICE_UUID], options: [CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey: true])
            break
        default: break
        }
    }

    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
        peripheral.discoverServices(nil)
        peripherals.append(peripheral)
    }

}

extension ViewController: CBPeripheralDelegate, CBPeripheralManagerDelegate {

    func peripheralManagerDidUpdateState(_ peripheral: CBPeripheralManager) {
        if peripheral.state == .poweredOn {
            initService()
            updateAdvertisingData()
        }
    }

    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverServices error: Error?) {
        for service in peripheral.services! {
            peripheral.discoverCharacteristics(nil, for: service)
        }
    }

    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor service: CBService, error: Error?) {
        for characteristic in service.characteristics! {
            let characteristic = characteristic as CBCharacteristic
            let message = "TestMessage".data(using: .utf8)
            peripheral.writeValue(message!, for: characteristic, type: CBCharacteristicWriteType.withResponse)
        }
    }

    func peripheralManager(_ peripheral: CBPeripheralManager, didReceiveWrite requests: [CBATTRequest]) {
        for request in requests {
            if let value = request.value {
                let messageText = String(data: value, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
                receiveLabel.text = messageText
            }
            self.peripheralManager.respond(to: request, withResult: .success)
        }
    }

    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
        peripheral.delegate = self
        peripheral.discoverServices(nil)
    }

}
```

Comment: You are attempting to write to every characteristic you discover; at least one of these requires encryption. If you only try and write to your own, specific, characteristic that doesn’t require encryption then you will not see the pairing prompt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though you only searched for peripherals that are advertising your specific service, when you discover a peripheral, you call

```
 peripheral.discoverServices(nil)
```

This will discover all services on the discovered peripheral (which is another iOS device), not just your specific service.

Then, for each service you discover all characteristics and for each characteristic you discover you write to it with

```
 let message = "TestMessage".data(using: .utf8)
 peripheral.writeValue(message!, for: characteristic, type: CBCharacteristicWriteType.withResponse)
```

Since you have discovered all characteristics for all services on the device and then attempt to write to each one, if any of those characteristics require encryption you will trigger the pairing dialog.  When you cancel the pairing dialog, that particular write will fail, but your app will keep on working (which is why you see the connection in settings).

You should refine your code so that it only discovers the specific service you are interested in and only attempts to write to your characteristic.  This will prevent the pairing dialog from being triggered as your characteristic does not require encryption.

Comment: Great answer, I worked it out by specifying the `discoverServices` with my `service uuid` and then in the `didDiscoverServices` I check if the service's uuid matches my service uuid before telling it to discover the characteristics. Now it works without triggering the popup